# Android: Creating multiple columns of buttons, each with independent scrollview

Tags: android, scroll, multiple-columns

This is a sample XML i've written. I'm trying to make a vertically aligned list of buttons, and 2 more columns of such. So there will be 3 columns in total. Each column will be vertically scrollable. How do you add more columns and make them individually scrollable?

I've searched and tried several other variations; the closest I could get to is with the tablelayout, but vertical scrolling seemed impossible with that!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/table" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:stretchColumns="*"> 

                <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/button1"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/button2"/>
                <Button
                     android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/button3"/>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: You can use `ListView`s, but I think having multiple lists side by side is not a good idea for small screens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use one horizontal `LinearLayout` as the root container and then one `ScrollView` for each column with equal width and containing a vertical `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1_1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1_2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1_3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2_1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2_2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2_3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3_1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3_2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3_3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks that helped! Can you share a good link that explains the acceptable parent-child relationships with layouts and how layouts work in general? Earlier, I attempted to have a table layout within a relative layout, but that made the parent layout (relative) useless/ ineffective.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a horizontal linear layout and placing three list views side by side putting their height as fill parent and width as 1/3 of total screen width each. Now you can put buttons in each list separately  and can scroll them independently. You can try this approach and see if it is what you want.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with :

```
<LinearLayout 
    ....
     android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ScrollView ...
       android:layout_weight="1">
      <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button android:id="@+id/b4">
        <Button android:id="@+id/b5">
        <Button android:id="@+id/b6">
      </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <ScrollView ...
       android:layout_weight="1">
      <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button android:id="@+id/b7">
        <Button android:id="@+id/b8">
        <Button android:id="@+id/b9">
      </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <ScrollView ...
       android:layout_weight="1">
      <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button android:id="@+id/b1">
        <Button android:id="@+id/b2">
        <Button android:id="@+id/b3">
      </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```